# Split by Caps in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split up a string by caps using Javascript,

Examples of what Im trying to do:

```
"HiMyNameIsBob"  ->   "Hi My Name Is Bob"
"GreetingsFriends" -> "Greetings Friends"
```

I am aware of the `str.split()` method, however I am not sure how to make this function work with capital letters.

I've tried:

```
str.split("(?=\\p{Upper})")
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work,
any help would be great.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use RegExp-literals, a look-ahead and `[A-Z]`:

```js
console.log(
  // -> "Hi My Name Is Bob"
  window.prompt('input string:', "HiMyNameIsBob").split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")  
)
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know it would be that easy, I couldn't find anything on Google, Thanks

Comment: Not to get picky here, but I needed this as well.  The answer above does NOT return "Hi My Name Is Bob".  It returns an array.  To actually get a string back of that, do this:  `input.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");`

Answer (score 9):

You can use String.match to split it.

```
"HiMyNameIsBob".match(/[A-Z]*[^A-Z]+/g) 
// output 
// ["Hi", "My", "Name", "Is", "Bob"]
```

If you have lowercase letters at the beginning it can split that too. If you dont want this behavior just use `+` instead of `*` in the pattern.

```
"helloHiMyNameIsBob".match(/[A-Z]*[^A-Z]+/g) 
// Output
["hello", "Hi", "My", "Name", "Is", "Bob"]
```

Comment: Neat, I didn't know that, Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The pattern has to be changed. Currently, it does not match preceding lowercase characters, or single uppercase characters.

Comment: IE does allow use of the split method.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko yes, in recent versions.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, thats not what your answer says though.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Where do you get the idea that `String.split` is not supported in IE? I've just summoned a VM, and String.split with a RegExp **works perfectly, even in IE6**. Also, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5az126b(v=vs.85).aspx) also confirms that it's supported.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko yes, OP didn't want it. But cant I show him the cross browser solution?

Comment: @RobW Sorry. I think I really am confused with `Array.indexOf`. I remember that it was documented in MDN. Now I dont find this in MDN.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im NP. [Use MDN](http://www.google.com/search?q=msdn+string.split), google as a primary reference for Javascript, and [MSDN](http://www.google.com/search?q=msdn+string.split+javascript) to validate statements about IE. Use virtualisation (to run multiple IE versions) to verify the documentated methods.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Rob W's answer.

This takes care of any sentences with abbreviations by checking for preceding lower case characters by adding `[a-z]`, therefore, it doesn't spilt any upper case strings.

```js
// Enter your code description here
 var str = "THISSentenceHasSomeFunkyStuffGoingOn. ABBREVIATIONSAlsoWork.".split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/).join(" ");  // -> "THIS Sentence Has Some Funky Stuff Going On. ABBREVIATIONS Also Work."
 console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for a text which starts from the small letter -

```
let value = "getMeSomeText";
let newStr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (value.charAt(i) === value.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
        newStr = newStr + ' ' + value.charAt(i)
      } else {
        (i == 0) ? (newStr += value.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) : (newStr += value.charAt(i));
      }
    }
    return newStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputString = "ThisIsAGoodExample";
const result = inputString.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");
console.log(result);
```

Answer: This Is A Good Example