# Function to split a phrase of the form "fooBar" into "foo bar" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

What's the best way to have a function that takes in a phrase of the form `fooBar` and returns the words `foo bar`?

My current approach of iterating over all characters to find a capitalized letter and then splitting on that index seems suboptimal is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: how splitting would return a small letter `b`?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is the good one, that is exactly what split function does with this pattern: `(?=[A-Z])`

```
var resultArray = mystring.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
```

The pattern uses a *lookahead assertion* `(?=...)` that means *followed by*.

Note: if you want to make lowercase all items of the result array, you can map the array like this:

```
resultArray = resultArray.map(function (x){ return x.toLowerCase(); });
```

Comment: Casimir: I didn't know of the followed by pattern, thanks.

Comment: @Aravind: Yes it's useful because a lookahead matches nothing (no characters are consumed), but it finds the position in the string. So the string is splitted with an empty delimiter.

Comment: What happens when you run this line on a word without a capital?

Comment: @Jongware: you obtain an array with only one word.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here suffices: [Split by Caps in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064683/split-by-caps-in-javascript)
Basically use a regex that looks for caps and does a split. To be complete the function is

```
function splitFooBar() {
 var fb = fooBar.split(/(?=[A-Z])/); 
 fbString = fb.length > 1? fb[0] + " " + fb[1].substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + fb[1].substr(1): fb[0];
 return fbString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```js
var re = /([A-Z])/g;
var str = 'fooBar fooBar fooBarww oldWman  ';
var subst = ' $1';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
result = result.toLowerCase();
console.log(result)
 alert(result)
```