# Is it possible to to split string with css to display that as separate words

Tags: html, css

If I have string like `<div>StringToSplit</div>` i want to display that string like `<div>String To Split</div>` is it possible to do that with css?

Basically I want to add space before each capital letter and wondering is that possible to do with css.

Comment: Why are you using a div for words? Why not just do:
<p>String To Split</p> and if that's not enough spacing, use word-spacing and increase it.. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/824sdk17/)

Comment: Do not have control on sever response. `word-spacing` not working for some reason, also i tryed to apply it inline with !important `style="word-spacing: 30px;!imoirtant`

Comment: Are you sure? Just to be sure, it needs to have a space inbetween them, e.g. <p>StringToSplit</p> will stay as StringToSplit unless you put spaces in between them, and it turns into [this](http://jsfiddle.net/scyn0azg/)

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript. With CSS probably not.

Comment: Css is designed for styling, js is made for manipulation. This falls under manipulation, so us going to require some js to do

Comment: word-break can be useful (though it's not in this case!)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524625/how-do-i-wrap-a-long-string-in-a-fixed-width-container-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No, or certainly not at the present time. You are going to need a little javascript to do this. The easiest way is @RobW answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10064697/1422377) stack overflow question.

Rob's answer was

```
"HiMyNameIsBob".split(/(?=[A-Z])/); // -> "Hi My Name Is Bob"
```

So for your situation it would be

```
"StringToSplit".split(/(?=[A-Z])/); // -> "String To Split"
```

This will return an array with the words split out, if you need a straight string the below should do it:

```
"StringToSplit".split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");
```