# How do I wrap a long string in a fixed-width container with CSS?

Tags: css

Lets say I have a fixed-width container with a long string inside, no spaces:

```css
div {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div>veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongstring</div>
```

**How do I force the text to wrap via CSS**? And what control do I have over that wrapping style (using a hyphen or not for example)?

I'm aware of the `text-wrap` property, but that doesn't seem to apply to a long string like this. Maybe I'm wrong. Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [`word-break` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break). You could use `word-break: break-all`:

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongstring</div>
```

Comment: funny, doesn't work for me in the 'Run code snippet'

Comment: @deW1 That's odd... I didn't realize `word-break: break-word` wasn't supported in FF... `break-all` seems to.

Comment: I was pretty sure that it was at least some time ago.

Comment: @deW1 Yeah, me too.. I've been using it for a few years without any issues.. if anything I just remember IE8 being problematic..

Answer (score 1):

This will also suffice

```css
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```