# Magick CSS that applies differently to each character of a string

Tags: html, css

(Contrary to appearances, this isn't a LaTeX question.)

In order to properly render with HTML the `\LaTeX` logo:

[image]

it is possible to make use of the following HTML input:

```html
<span class="LATEX">L<span class="A">A</span><span class="TEX">T<span class="E">E</span>X</span></span>
```

and the following CSS code:

```css
span.TEX {letter-spacing: -0.125em; margin-right:0.125em;}
span.TEX span.E{ position:relative;top:0.5ex;left:-0.0417em;}
a span.TEX span.E {text-decoration: none; }
span.LATEX span.A{ position:relative; top:-0.5ex; left:-0.4em; font-size:85%;}
span.LATEX span.TEX{ position:relative; margin-left: -0.4em; margin-right:0.125em; }
```

Is there a way to obtain the same result with a shorter HTML input, such as in the following pseudocode:

```html
<span class="LATEXLogo">LaTeX</span>
```

and the following CSS code:

```css
span.LATEXLogo { something magick }
```

Comment: This is roughly the same question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467540/is-it-possible-to-to-split-string-with-css-to-display-that-as-separate-words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to to split string with css to display that as separate words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467540/is-it-possible-to-to-split-string-with-css-to-display-that-as-separate-words)

Comment: @A.Meshu I don't see to apply the linked question to the current one.

Comment: You split on every character in the element so use `.` in the regex instead of the lookahead. With that you can iterate over and apply styles to each character.

Comment: @user3783243 Sorry, but beyond my scope.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé , as pointed there css can't do that. Your markup is different but it's the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my own I can offer a solution for javascript.

Here, each character is wrapped in a separate `<inside>` tag. Further, with the help of `pseudo-classes` in `css`, you can refer to even and not even letters with a word:

```
inside:nth-child(odd) {
  /*your styles*/
}

inside:nth-child(even) {
  /*your styles*/
}
```

Or you can assign unique styles to each letter of the word. Like this:

```
inside:nth-child(1) {
  /*your styles*/
}

inside:nth-child(2) {
  /*your styles*/
}

...

inside:nth-child(5) {
  /*your styles*/
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let text = document.querySelector('.LATEXLogo');
  let inside = '';

  for (i = 0; i < text.innerText.length; i++) {
    if (text.innerText[i] !== " ") {
      inside += "<inside>";
      inside += text.innerText[i];
      inside += "</inside>";
    }
  }
  text.innerHTML = inside;
}
```

```css
inside:nth-child(odd) {
  color: red;
}

inside:nth-child(even) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="LATEXLogo">LaTeX</span>
```

Comment: Indeed, just a matter of a missing `window.onload` :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé, glad to help :)

Comment: Well, if the number of occurrences of `<span class="LATEXLogo">LaTeX</span>` is > 1, only the first one is displayed as expected.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé, Yes. And in order to apply this to many occurrences, you need to change the call to the selector. Like this - `document.querySelectorAll`. And this is not the only change in the code that needs to be done.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé, do you need help making code for many `<span class="LATEXLogo">LaTeX</span>`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé, good :) If you have any difficulties or questions, then let me know, please.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.latex sub, .latex sup {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.latex sub {
  vertical-align: -0.5ex;
  margin-left: -0.1667em;
  margin-right: -0.125em;
}

.latex, .latex sub {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.latex sup {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  vertical-align: 0.15em;
  margin-left: -0.36em;
  margin-right: -0.15em;
}
```

```html
<span class="latex">L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span></p>
```

---

Another option, without any `css`/`html`, using [MathJax cdn](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"> </script>
\(\rm\LaTeX\)
```

Comment: Nice! But is it possible with something even simpler: `<span class="latex">LaTeX</p>`?

Comment: Nope, since you'll need to target each individual character, using `<sub>` and `<sup>` is the easiest way.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé, it is possible, but with the help of javascript.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Why not with javascript?

Comment: About the javascript option, is it possible to directly get this logo without rely on LaTeX's math mode (`\(...\)`) and be able to just write `\LaTeX`?