# How split the months from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I need to split only month names from a string .

Ex :

```
let str = "januaryfebruaryapriltuesdayfriday";
```

I want to split like

```
let arr = ["january","february"," april "]
```

I am new to JS , I have tried split method ,but i didn't get the result ,is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: you can use capital letter . It is already here .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064683/split-by-caps-in-javascript

Comment: It may be as small case also

Comment: Since there's day names ( and maybe other things ? ) in there as well, the easiest solution will be to just have an array with all 12 month names and map that to the string to know which months occur in the string. But the better solution would be to prevent having this problem in the first place by adjusting whatever gave you that string.

Comment: Any examples u have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for searching for month names and get an array of it.

```js
var string = "januaryfebruaryapriltuesdayfriday",
    array = string.match(/january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december/gi);
    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Easiest without any loops!! Awesome answer @nina scholz

Comment: I agree, @nina scholz is the best in the business when it comes to these JS issues

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following.

To explain, firstly create an array of all the months.

You then want to `filter` into a new array by only including the months that are in the string.

```js
let months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];

// change all months to lowercase
months = months.map(m => {
  return m.toLowerCase();
});


let str = "januaryfebruaryapriltuesdayfriday";
let arr = months.filter(m => str.includes(m));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I had the same idea and just implemented another way around! good try! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
let str = "januaryfebruaryapriltuesdayfriday";
let months=['january','february', 'march', 'april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december'];
let arr=[];
months.map((data,index)=>{
if(str.indexOf(data)>=0){
  arr.push(str.substr(str.indexOf(data),data.length))
}}
)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: his string only contains lowercase letters

Comment: I think it will return all the values rit ? I need month names only

Comment: It  was upper case when i posted the answer @PaulFitzgerald

Comment: Please check it now @parithiinfo

Comment: @Wysiati fair enough, I didn't see that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
    let str = "januaryfebruaryapriltuesdayfriday";
    var arr = [];
    if( str.includes("january") ) {
     arr.push("january");
    }
    if( str.includes("february") ) {
     arr.push("february");
    }
    if( str.includes("april") ) {
     arr.push("april");
    }
    console.log(arr);
```

Continue doing the same for all the months.

**How does this work?**

This will check if your string contains the names of the months (january, february, march, and so on...) - and if a specific month was found in the string, it will be pushed (appended/added) to the array which is called `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```js
var monthsArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
var input = "januaryfeBruaryapriltuesdayfriday";
var inputLowerCase = input.toLowerCase();
var output = [];
monthsArray.forEach(function (month) {
    if (input.includes(month.toLowerCase())) {
        output.push(month);
    }
});
console.log("Output:", output);
```

// Output: (2) ["January", "April"]